# Problem in cell dimension assignment from "save as" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, resolution

I am trying to save one raster in QGIS by changing the cell dimensions. I select 30 x 30 as cell resolution, but then the output raster has a resolution of 29.9985 x 29.9985.

How can I assign exactly 30 as cell resolution?

Comment: you can use gdalwarp for change resolution.The result is exactly 30x30

Comment: It works! Do you know why the QGIS instruction is not precise?